# must i inform the user to give me permission to access the cashed application folder

Tags: flutter

i am making flutter application handle with videos , audios , images , all from server  and there big part handling with cache application folder . save , cashed .. etc ..

i am wondering if i must inform the user to give me permission for that or not ? (only cashed folder )

anyone has know more about this please give me suggestion

```
late Directory getMainPathh;
  Future getTheCasheDirectoryPath()async{
    getMainPathh  = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to ask the user for permission. This directory can always be cleaned by the user or the system themselves if needed.

Comment: thanks .. what about getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() ? same ? .. and what do you mean of  system themselves ? you mean system maybe clean up auto ? without from user order ?

Comment: getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()  should also work without permission as almost every app needs a local storage. The OS (Android/iOS) will delete the cache files automatically if it needs more memory or storage.

Comment: then i don't need any plugin that cashed the media , since i can use local storage free .. i am wrong ?

Comment: You're right, use the storage as you like :)